# Closed set in the product space implies sequential closure

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let $(X, \ge)$ be an ordered topological space. Let $\succsim$ be another order relation on $X \times X$ such that for all $x,y,z,w \in X$ the set $$\{(x,y,z,w) \in X \times X \times X \times X : (x,y) \succcurlyeq (z,w) \}$$ is closed in the product topology.

Suppose $(x_n)$, $(y_n), (w_n)$, $(z_n)$ converge to $x$, $y$, $w$ and $z$ respectively. If for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $(x_n,y_n) \succsim (w_n,z_n)$ then $(x,y) \succsim (w,z).$

My tentative proof is:

i) Show that component-wise convergence is equivalent to convergence of the quadruple in the product space (known result).

ii) Denote $K = \{(x,y,w,z) \in X \times X \times X \times X : (x,y) \succsim (w,z)\}$ and pick a sequence of points with values in $K$ converging to $(x,y,w,z)$. Since every closed set in the product topology is sequentially closed, the conclusion follows.

Does it sound correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that argument works as closed sets are always sequentially closed (the reverse need not hold, but that's not an issue here). IN the last step you don't have to *pick* such a sequence of points, as the $(x_n,y_n)$ and $(w_n, x_n)$ are already given such that $(x_n, y_n, w_n, z_n)$ are in $K$ aren't they ? They converge to $(x,y)$ and $(w,z)$ resp. because of the convergence iff pointwise convergence fact in all product topologies.

Comment: You are right. Here I applied the known result of topologically closed implies sequentially closed and the $\textit{pick}$ term came from a possible proof of that fact. But yes, you are right, I do not pick any sequence, I just use the one I have by assumption.